# Gifting/sharing app to Family child's iPad without App Sharing?

Tags: family-sharing

I'm seeing apps, through my own iPhone/iPad, that I'd like to get on to my son's iPad. I'd just like to somehow beam them over there, or download on my device and share with his. Is there a way to do this?

I don't need to become the sole buyer of apps on his and his mother's devices again, like my understanding of Purchase Sharing.

I set up Family Sharing a while ago. There's me, my son and my partner. It's pretty locked-down for the child.

Initially, I set up Purchase Sharing, but I undid that when I realised it simply made me the sole purchaser for apps bought by both him and his mother. That wasn't necessary. Instead, I set up a family bank card against the child's account and required permission for all purchases.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, one of the benefits of Family Sharing is that one person (the Organiser) can take responsibility for purchases of all apps, books, music, etc. on family devices even when the users of those devices have their own Apple ID allowing contacts, messaging, etc. to be kept separate from those of the Organiser.

That is the method you should be using even if there are some frustrations.  You could just add your son's account to the 'family' leaving your partner to manage her own purchases (if that is appropriate for your family).

You can't just transfer/share an app from your Apple ID to another Apple ID. That would be open to abuse. Family sharing was introduced to satisfy your needs whilst allowing Apple to maintain control of the use of purchases.

Comment: Apple's assumption that I want to buy apps for both my son and my partner is faulty. What I'm seeking is the ability to authorise/buy an app for the child from my device that appears on his. Instead, turning on Purchase Sharing allows both child and partner to buy apps on their devices with my card. That doesn't satisfy the use case.

Comment: If you buy the app on your device, you (or your son) can then download (without additional cost) on his device.  But not exactly what you want.  I guess you have to work with what Apple provides.